# How to upload image in array input type

Tags: laravel, file-upload, laravel-5.6

I want to upload image using `protected function create(array $data){}`

Below code is used for `public function create(Request $request){}`

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
        $image = new Image();
        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $dir = 'uploads/';
            $extension = strtolower($request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension()); // get image extension
            $fileName = str_random() . '.' . $extension; // rename image
            $request->file('image')->move($dir, $fileName);
            $image->image = $fileName;
        }
        $image->save();
        return view('here');
    }
}
```

I tried the following code but gets error

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
        $dir = '/customer/images/';
        $extension = strtolower($data['image']->getClientOriginalExtension()); // get image extension
        $fileName = str_random() . '.' . $extension; // rename image
        $data['image']->move($dir, $fileName);
        $data['image'] = $fileName;

    return Image::create([
        'image' => $data['image'],
    ]);
}
```

I'm getting error. How can i upload image using array.

Comment: Please add the error to your question.

Comment: See first if there is any similar answer to your question.. for more see this if can relate to your problem. good luck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47994118/how-to-upload-array-of-image-files-using-multipart-in-android-volley-library

Comment: i think you need to specify the public path like this move(public_path($dir, $fileName)) if you paste the error here it would be better so we can figure out the problem